# Lodash forEach is not a function - after Angular CLI update

Tags: angular, lodash, angular-cli

I have been using Lodash in Angular CLI 2.2.3 without any issues. However after updating Angular CLI to  2.3.1 I have been experiencing a few issues. First error was Error: Cannot find module 'lodash' in angular-cli?.
I resolved this issue by doing:

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev
```

and adding to angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js”],
```

That allowed the my angular 2 project to compile without error. However when I go to a component that uses a lodash foreach I get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./FormDetailComponent class FormDetailComponent - inline template:5:73 caused by: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_lodash__.forEach is not a function
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_lodash__.forEach is not a function
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:55 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:55
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:56 TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_lodash__.forEach is not a function
    at FormTableComponent.setTotalFlex (form-table.component.ts:92)
    at FormTableComponent.ngOnInit (form-table.component.ts:64)
    at Wrapper_FormTableComponent.ngDoCheck (wrapper.ngfactory.js:54)
    at View_FormDetailComponent3.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:126)
    at View_FormDetailComponent3.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
    at View_FormDetailComponent3.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:67)
    at View_FormDetailComponent1.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:261)
    at View_FormDetailComponent1.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
    at View_FormDetailComponent1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (view_container.js:67)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_FormDetailComponent0.detectChangesInternal (component.ngfactory.js:326)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:425)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:620)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (view.js:410)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:56
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:59 ERROR CONTEXT:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:60 DebugContext {_view: View_FormDetailComponent3, _nodeIndex: 4, _tplRow: 5, _tplCol: 73}
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:60
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught ViewWrappedError {_nativeError: Error: Error in ./FormDetailComponent class FormDetailComponent - inline template:5:73 caused by: __…, originalError: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_lodash__.forEach is not a function
    at FormTableComponent…, context: DebugContext}
```

I am importing the lodash function into my component like:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Also here is how I am using foreach in my code:

```
printYArr(): void {
    this.totalFlex  = [];
    // Get y
    let yArr: number[] = [];
    // Get array of y
    _.forEach(this.elements, function(obj: FormElement) {
      if (yArr.indexOf(obj.y) < 0) {
        yArr.push(obj.y);
      }
    });
    console.log('yarr',yArr);
  }
```

My package main dependancies are as follows.

```
"@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
```

Anyone else coming across this issue and can help me resolve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using _.each instead of _.forEach?  Do you get the same type of error?  Btw, I've never had that issue.  This is a stab in the dark; it shouldn't work, but it's worth a shot.